# return only collection of id's from eloquent model in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to return collection of my user model, but only with user_id column. I have one mutator for calculating age(not saved in database) and it is always return with model collection. How to excluded this "append"attribute from all() method ?
In my controller "index" method:

```
$users = User::all();
```

In "users" collection I dont want ( by default ) to have "age" attribute.

In my "User" model:

```
public function getAgeAttribute (){
     // calculate age from date_of_birth
}
```

Comment: Add your code and explain what you want the end result to be.

Comment: i edited my question...

Comment: So you want `getAgeAttribute()` to be executed for all *age* attributes in the collection?

Comment: Mutators only give value when you call to it. How did you checked the existance of attribute on a model instance?

Comment: You can return list of ids only : `return $users->lists('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
$users = User::all();
$users->map(function($user) {
    $user["age"] = $user->getAgeAttribute();
});
```

It append age of each user into `$users`.